# MPAndroidChart real-time graph

Tags: android, real-time, mpandroidchart

I continuously add data to LineData and it works well up to some point. Usually it happens after X-axis index surpass 1000. I believe that the data added to the graph is not removed once some amount of new data arrive. Do I need to remove the values myself or does the library provide some recycling?

Also, when scrolling back, scrolling is allowed only up to some X index, and then it automatically jumps to max index in LineData once that specific X index is reached. How could the amount we can scroll back be controlled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I implemented. Works like a charm.

```
if(dataSet[i].getEntryCount() == NumberOfPointYouCareAbout) {
       mChartData[i].removeXValue(0);
       dataSet[i].removeEntry(0);

       for (Entry entry : dataSet[i].getYVals()) {
           entry.setXIndex(entry.getXIndex() - 1);
       }
 }
```